# Can 2 H-Brides be controlled by one Arduino?

Tags: motor, robotics, h-bridge

The three motors are from windshield wipers, with one of the brushes disconnected in each. The controllers are BTS7960 43A modules

One Bridge for two drive motors (speed and direction), and the second Bridge for a third [modified servo-like] motor (for Ackerman steering).

Is this possible/recommended?

Comment: Yes. Why would you suppose it wasn't?

Comment: never seen it before, always one arduino one driver.

Comment: That's because for many projects one driver is enough.

Comment: @Majenko i see. at the risk of noob-shaming, can you please give an extremely brief review of the project. it's three wiper motors; 2 behind for drive and one front like an RC car servo for steering. input from an on-board ROS computer to the arduino (USB), to each BTS7960 bridge for movement control. and controlling four separated strips of WS2812B smart LEDs

recap: can one arduino work with 1) continuous USB input from a computer 2)controlling 2 separate h-bridges 3) controlling smart LED strips 4)all at the same time

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between using one and using two drivers. It's just the number of pins of the different types that you need.

Comment: many thanks @Majenko